# How do I give global access to an object in Scala without making it a singleton or passing it to everything?

Tags: scala, singleton

I have a Logger class that logs events in my application. While I only need one instance of the logger in this application, I want this class to be reusable, so I don't want to make it a singleton and couple it with my specific needs for this application.

I want to be able to access this Logger instance from anywhere in the application without having to create a new one every time or pass it around to every class that might need to log something. What I currently do is have an ApplicationUtils singleton that I use as the point of access for the application's Logger:

```
object ApplicationUtils {
    lazy val log : Logger = new Logger()
}
```

Then I have a Loggable trait that I add to classes that need the Logger:

```
trait Loggable {
    protected[this] lazy val log = ApplicationUtils.log
}
```

Is this a valid approach for what I am trying to accomplish? It feels a little hack-y. Is there a better approach I could be using? I'm pretty new to Scala.

Comment: When you say "without making it a singleton or passing it to everything", you eliminate your only two options. That said, you can make "passing it to everything" a lot less painful than it sounds, since you only need to pass it to things that actually need to log. See "Dead-simple dependency injection": http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZasXwtTRkio

Answer (score 5):

Be careful when putting functionality in `object`s. That functionality is easily testable, but if you need to test clients of that code to make sure they interact with it correctly (via mocks and spies), you're stuck 'cause objects compile to final classes and thus cannot be mocked.

Instead, use this pattern:

```
trait T { /* code goes here */ }

object T extends T /* pass this to client code from main sources */
```

Now you can create Mockito mocks / spies for `trait T` in your test code, pass that in and confirm that the interactions of the code under test with the `trait T` code are what they should be.

If you have code that's a client of T and whose interactions with it don't require testing, you can directly reference `object T`.

Comment: This is for part of a research project for school, so there won't be any testing simply due to time constraints, but that's something I will keep in mind for future projects.

Answer (score 5):

To address what you're trying to do (rather than what you're asking), take a look at TypeSafe's [scalalogging](https://github.com/typesafehub/scalalogging) package. It provides a `Logging` trait that you can use like so:

```
class MyClass extends Logging {
  logger.debug("This is very convenient ;-)")
}
```

It's a macro-based wrapper for SLF4J, so something like `logger.debug(...)` gets compiled as `if (logger.isDebugEnabled) logger.debug(...)`.

Comment: My question wasn't just about logging, it was weather the approach I was using is a valid scala pattern..That being said, it seems that the  Logging trait you mention implements the same functionality as my Loggable trait.